# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies.

Tags: asp.net

I am facing issue on server, it is saying that System.Windows.dll could not found. At First time execution, it is throwing Exception but after refreshing page it is working fine.

I figured out, this is happening because of ScriptManager. I have ScriptManager on my page, see the error below:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 


Line 148:        <img src="../../Images/loading.gif" width="500" />
Line 149:    </div>
Line 150:    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
Line 151:    </asp:ScriptManager>
Line 152:    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">


Source File: d:\xyz\CRM\Reports\zyz.aspx    Line: 150 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' could not be loaded.


WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Answer (score 0):

You will find the dll in the references folder:

```
Copy local = true
```

Set this property on the assembly.

Build, and it should work.

If not:

copy this dll into the project and set copy to output directory = Copy if newer

**EDIT:**

Try to use this scriptmanager:

[Download from here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/)

[ToolkitScriptManager](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FHAb_FlcbLA)

Comment: I tried this approach but System.Windows.dll is added as reference in Silverlight solution not in Web Application. i made it as Copy local = true. now error is changed to Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0. Also now System.Windows.dll is showing in Silverlight bin folder but while deploying web. it is not showing in bin folder of web. Please reply

Comment: Also As I mention above in main question, this error is coming because of ScriptManager tag. if i am removing ScriptManager and UpdatePanel from my page. It is working fine. I am not able to figure out why it is happening.

Comment: try this on the dll: Specific version = false

Comment: It is already Specific version = false. I just changed Copy local =true.

Comment: Yes .. here is tag <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: I see, you can try to create a new empty project, and put scriptmanager on the page. If it works correctly, try to move your content, and maybe it helps to investigate the proble, or it solves it. Second option, there is a better scriptmanager here http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/ In this package you can use toolkitscriptmanager. I think there won't be a problem with it.

Comment: I can't use ajaxtoolkit because i am having aroung 10 seprate page where i am using SciptManager, Also situation is that i can't create Master page and put one ajaxtolkit scriptmangaer. i tried separate solution with default script manger but the same problem coming on server after deployment.

Comment: Ok, solution: copy this dll into the project and set copy to output directory = Copy if newer

Comment: which dll i have to copy?

Comment: System.Windows you find it in GAC C:\Windows\assembly

Comment: Try with System.Windows.Forms, in theoretically it's good too